# How to remove a specific character from a string, only when it is the first or last character in the string.

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a string `1,2,3,`  I would like to remove the last `,` or if the string looks like `,1,2,3,` or   `,1,2,3` I would still like to get `1,2,3` as my result. 
And please try to be a little explanatory in your answer. I do not just want to copy paste stuff without understanding it. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to remove extra commas in the beginning or end of the string? I ask as the end goal might point to other possible solutions.

Comment: I am sending a long string which looks like `a,b,c` to my stored procedure and I am using this in my `IN clause` , I am removing the last occurrence of comma from code behind  , I was curious how I can do the same in sql.

Comment: Check out [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) method in SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way to deal with "trimming" commas like that would be using a `CASE` statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN str LIKE ',%,' THEN SUBSTRING(str, 2, LEN(str)-2)
    WHEN str LIKE ',%'  THEN RIGHT(str, LEN(str)-1)
    WHEN str LIKE '%,'  THEN LEFT(str, LEN(str)-1)
    ELSE str
END
```

This is very much self-explanatory: the `CASE` statement considers three situations -

- When the string `str` has commas on both sides,
- When the string `str` starts in a comma, but does not end in one, and
- When the string `str` ends in a comma, but does not start in one.

In the first case, the first and the last characters are removed; in the second case, the leftmost character is removed; in the last case, the trailing character is removed.

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42c00/1)

Comment: Your solution will work in most of the cases but what if my string looks like ..  `1,2,3,,` or `a,b,c,,` ? I know this is not very likely but lets just assume it happens what then? +1 btw

Comment: @Arbaaz Since SQL Server 2008 lacks "plain" support for regex, dealing with character sequences of unknown length is a tricky issue. You could write your own function, or resort to a hack: replace commas with spaces, trim spaces on both ends, and finally replace spaces with commas again, like this `REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(str,',', ' '))),' ', ',')` ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1fbef/1)). **Note:** the original string must *not* contain spaces in order for this hack to work.

Comment: @Arbaaz, that isn't exactly fair of you. Your question is specifically dealing with First and/or Last character. Please update the wording of your question so answers given can be more appropriate.

Comment: @srutzky the answer given by dasblinkenlight is pretty satisfactory to me. And I will mark his answer soon if there are no other better answers to do what i asked in my `original` question.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @str varchar(20)=',1,2,3,'

select   case
         when @str like ',%,' then stuff(stuff(@str, 1, 1, ''),LEN(stuff(@str, 1, 1, '')),1,'')

         when @str like ',%' then stuff(@str, 1, 1, '')

         when @str like '%,' then stuff(@str, LEN(@str), 1, '')

         else @str
         end
```

Answer (score 0):

`dept_name` is column name and 'I' is a character you want to replace.

```
SELECT REPLACE(Dept_Name,'I','')
FROM [Newone].[dbo].[Department]
where Dept_Name like 'I%' or Dept_Name like  '%I'
```

Comment: He want only the first and last.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` would work here. I'm thinking something like this:

```
CASE 

WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(YourString, 1)) <> 1 AND ISNUMERIC(LEFT(YourString, 1)) <> 1
THEN SELECT MID(YourString, 2, LEN(YourString) - 2)

WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(YourString, 1)) <> 1
THEN SELECT LEFT(YourString, LEN(YourString) -1)

WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(YourString, 1)) <> 1
THEN SELECT RIGHT(YourString, LEN(YourString) - 1)

ELSE SELECT YourString

END
```

This works no matter what the character is as it checks to see if the first and last are numeric first, if not get your new string, else check to see if the end is numeric if not select the string besides the end, else check to see if the beginning is numeric if not select the string besides the beginning, else get your string.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace just one comma (as it is in your original question) in the start or in the end then:

```
CASE
    WHEN str LIKE '%,%' THEN 
       SUBSTRING(str, IIF(LEFT(str,1)=',',2,1), 
                      LEN(str)-IIF(LEFT(str,1)=',',1,0)
                              -IIF(RIGHT(str,1)=',',1,0))
    ELSE str
END
```

If `,,,,1,2,3,,,,` is possible then use [PATINDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) function with `'%[0-9]%` mask:

```
CASE
    WHEN str LIKE '%,%' THEN 
       SUBSTRING(str, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',str), 
                      LEN(str)-(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',str)-1)
                              -(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE(str))-1))
    ELSE str

END
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c03c/2)</kbd>

Comment: although he want first and last but what if the is like this ,,,1,,2,,,,,3,,

Comment: @Jade Then `1,,2,,,,,3` will remain. @Arbaaz wants to remove `,` "only when it is the first or last character in the string".

Comment: Yes, that is why i said although and what if.

Comment: @Jade Then you should use a few nested REPLACE functions. For example: `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Str,',,',','),',,',','),',,',',')`

Comment: Agreed! And this were nothing to do with the question already, again 3 nested replace what if there are 4 pair of ''? And @valex just asking because there is a possibility that someone might need something like this.

Answer (score 0):

A few options, all using SQLCLR, if that is something that you are not denied access to. You can write your own functions to do these things but the examples I will show are based on the [SQL# (SQLsharp)](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library. I am the author of the SQL# library, but the first 2 examples are using functions available in the Free version.  The 3rd example, using TrimChars(), is not Free but I included it for completeness since it was just so simple ;-). In each example, the characters inside of the pre or post extra commas can be anything.

1. A somewhat simple Regular Expression for use in a Capture Group to get everything from the first non-comma value through the last non-comma value:

   ```
   SELECT SQL#.RegEx_CaptureGroup(N',,12,123,12334,567,,,,,',
                                  N'^,*(.+?),*$', -- Regular Expression
                                  1, -- Capture Group to return
                                  '', -- not found replacement
                                  1, -- Start At position
                                  -1, -- Length
                                  '' -- RegEx Options
                                  )
   ```
2. If the reason for removing the extra commas is to get a clean list for splitting, you can split them and have the split function remove the empty values for you and hence not need to worry about where empty values are, even if in the middle:

   ```
   SELECT *FROM SQL#.String_Split(N',,12,123,12334,567,,,,,', N',', 2)
   -- 2 = remove empty values
   ```
3. You can do a simple Trim that removes the specified character from both sides until it finds a character that is not the character to Trim:

   ```
   SELECT SQL#.String_TrimChars(N',,12,123,12334,567,,,,,', N',')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove a trailing comma, in SQL Server, I'd use the STUFF function, and it would look something like this:

```
SELECT STRING, stuff(string, (len(string) - 1),1,'') as newstring
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(fld),2,LEN(fld)))
```

It will always take of the last character regardless.
You can put a CASE WHEN statement to ensure the last character is comma by simply saying

```
CASE 
WHEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(fld,1,1))=',' THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(fld),2,LEN(fld))) 
ELSE fld
END fld
```